# How do you calloc a global variable to the size of input parameters in C++?

Tags: c++, global-variables, calloc

I'm using a `portaudio` callback where because of interrupts and such its suggested you don't allocate or free in the callback.

```
  float *out_pcm = (float *)calloc(sizeof(float), frames);
```

My C++ is very basic but right or wrong how do you set array shape (frames) of a global variable?

Can you create a global variable
`float *out_pcm;`

Then in a function or main set the index size with something like

```
out_pcm = calloc(sizeof(float), frames);
```

?

Comment: In C++ you should not use `calloc` at all, really. `std::vector<float> out_pcm(frames);` should work just as well (if not better). And yes, if you need to get a raw non-owning pointer to the actual data it's possible, `out_pcm.data()` provides that.

Comment: As for the issue of global variables and assignment, you can define a variable in any scope you like, and then initialize or assign to it anywhere. *But* global variables are really not recommended. Define locally, and pass as arguments to the functions that needs the variables. Or wrap in classes, and pass objects to the functions. And if you use a vector or a custom class, remember to pass *by reference*.

Comment: You shouldn't use globals, you should use the "user data" parameter. Read some [tutorials](http://files.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/writing_a_callback.html).

Comment: I have and the tutorial didn't make that much sense at 1st but yeah passed as user_data.
I am trying to create a delay_sum beamformer I am not even a programmer never mind C++ as not one exists for Linux!!? So thanks guys and apols as this is a very steep learning curve for me.

Comment: If you don't know the size until the callback then you have to allocate it in the callback - there's no other option

Answer (score 0):

```
  void paFunc(const float* in, float* out, long frames, void* data){    
  auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
  paConfig *config = (paConfig*)data;  
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
  struct paConfig config;
  config.channels = channels;
  config.margin = margin;
  config.out_pcm = (float *)calloc(sizeof(float), frames);
  config.tdoa = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), channels);
  config.in_data = (float *)calloc(sizeof(float), frames * channels);
  config.beam_data = (float *)calloc(sizeof(float), frames * channels);
  
  
  Pa a(paFunc, channels, 1, sample_rate, frames, &config);
```

Apols yeah should use std::vector out_pcm(frames); but things are slowly getting better